# Prove the linear transformation that takes all linear maps $T: V\to W$ to their respective matrix representations is an isomorphism.

Tags: matrices, functions, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $V$, $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces.
Prove the linear transformation that takes all linear maps $T: V\to W$ to their respective matrix representations is an isomorphism.
Thanks in advance!

I know it has to be onto and one-to-one, but I don't know how to explicitly show it is both injective and surjective.

Comment: Unless you first specify bases for $V$ and $W$, there is no well-defined linear transformation to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that this map is injective means showing that if two transformations have the same matrix representation, they must be the same.

Showing that this map is surjective means showing that any matrix has an associated matrix representation.

You can do both in one move as follows: if you have a matrix, show that there is one and only one linear transformation which that matrix represents.  Namely, show (probably using the definition of a "matrix representation") the matrix $A$ can only represent the transformation given by
$$
T(x) = Ax
$$

Comment: This is false unless you first specify bases. A given matrix can represent lots of different linear transformations.

Comment: @Ted It looks like I assumed from the nature of the question that the linear transformation being discussed takes a given transformation to its representation relative to some already specified basis. Within that context, the statement seems fine to me.

Comment: Of course this old post was unearthed because of a silly edit. I don’t see any reference whatsoever to bases in the OP. If new people are going to read the post, I wanted this issue to be crystal-clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a basis $B_1 :v_1, v_2, ... v_n$ of $V$ and basis $B_2 : w_1, w_2, ... w_m$ of $W$, a linear transformation $f : V \rightarrow W$ is determined entirely by the values of $f(v_1), f(v_2), ... f(v_n)$ in $W$. So if $g$ and $h$ are different linear maps from $V$ to $W$, then $g(v_i) \neq h(v_i)$, for some $1 \leq i \leq n$. Therefore the coordinates of $g(v_i)$ and $h(v_i)$ in $B_2$ are different, hence the $i^{th}$ column in the corresponding matrices are different. That shows that the map is one-to-one. The 'onto' part is even easier, because for every $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ vectors of $W$ there is linear map $t$, such that $t(v_i) = a_i$ and every matrix $m$ x $n$ defines such $n$ vectors.